# "unit tests have failed" for beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

i am trying to install beautifulsoup for python33 but its not installing properly it gives error like that:

```
C:\Python33>pip install beautifulsoup
Downloading/unpacking beautifulsoup
Downloading BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
Running setup.py egg_info for package beautifulsoup
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "c:\windows\temp\pip_build_Prashant\beautifulsoup\setup.py", line 22
    print "Unit tests have failed!"
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

File "c:\windows\temp\pip_build_Prashant\beautifulsoup\setup.py", line 22

print "Unit tests have failed!"

                              ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

so what can i do for this error,can anybody suggest me?

Comment: You want `beautifulsoup4`; BS 3 is very old and won't work on Python 3.

Comment: is this work same like beautifulsoap?

Comment: @Prashant: It is the newest version of that project.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You are trying to install BeautifulSoup 3, which is not Python 3 compatible. Install [`beautifulsoup4`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4) instead:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Most code that assumes BeautifulSoup 3 will also work with BeautifulSoup 4. For new projects, just stick with BS4.

Comment: That is the most unfortunate choice of version number ever. Of course one would expect BeautifulSoup 3 to work with Python 3!

Comment: @MarkRansom: not sure if you are serious or not. BS3 was first released in 2006, a good 2 years before Python 3 came out. There are tons of software packages at version 3 or 4 without regards to Python 3's release schedule.

Comment: Yes, I'm serious. The least they could have done was updated the package to inform you that a different package is required for Python 3, so that you don't have to scour the internet wondering what happened.

Comment: I do agree that the project should not have switched names like that, or at the very least have put out a transition release option. But has very little to do with version numbers. Note that the [project documentation page](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is pretty explicit as to what should be installed.

Comment: Who looks at documentation? When I want to install a package, I do `python -m pip install package` and don't give it a second thought.

Comment: Why did they not just keep updating the original `beautifulsoup`? What is the point of doing a rename like that at all?

Comment: @CoreyLevinson: presumably because BeautifulSoup 4 is not entirely backwards compatible. Projects using BeautifulSoup 3 can't all be upgraded to BeautifulSoup 4 without breaking. Without the rename, any project using automatic dependency management could have broken.